# nested while loop - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, nested

The question is really simple I guess, but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.
I've a nested while loop and two rows.
The result should be:

```
ManU - Arsenal
Chelsea - Liverpool
ManCity - Everton
Tottenham - Fulham
```

but what I got is this:

```
LiverpoolEvertonFulham
ManU - Arsenal
Chelsea - 
ManCity -
Tottenham -
```

This is the code:

```
$row1 = array('ManU','Chelsea','ManCity', 'Tottenham');
$row2 = array('Arsenal','Liverpool','Everton', 'Fulham');

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    echo "<table>";
    while($i < count($row1)){
        $a = $row1[$i];
        echo "<tr><td>".$a." - ";
        $i++;

        while($j < count($row2)){
            $b = $row2[$j];
            echo $b."</td></tr>";   
            $j++;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

The thing is it must be a nested while loop because in fact I'm using SQL, and this is just a simplified version of the problem (rows instead of db table rows), on the other version the problem is the same, so it's not a SQL problem, i think. Please help!

Comment: no time...use for($i=0;$i<count(...);$i++) I think will solve your issues. hint - you never zero your second loop after first itteration.

Comment: Where are you not using a simple `for` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 loops

```
while($i < count($row1)){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row1[$i]." - ".$row2[$i]."</td></tr>";
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Not in this case, but I can't do this with mysql_fetch_array.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<tr><td><p>".$row['team_name']." - ".$row2['team_name'];
} ...

Comment: Wouldn't you fetch the 2 arrays before the loop? So the only difference to the example above is the source of $row1 and $row2 - the loop itself would be the same.

Comment: My answer is given based on the question you asked and it gives the output you want.

Comment: Yes I know, and thanks! I'll try to fetch them before, but I'm not sure that's the solution.

Comment: @Nino Biuk have you tested it ??? `but I'm not sure that's the solution` .. very funny

Comment: Why is it funny? I'm not sure what ALL I'm tested in the last two days!

Comment: Oh, you mean that... Of course It works. Read all posts and comments carefully ;)

Comment: Hey, Ted, you are a life saver. That was an brilliant idea with the fetch before loop. Thanks!

Comment: @NinoBiuk you shouldn't have unaccepted this answer as it was the answer to question you asked. I understand it wasn't the answer to the end problem you were having, but you didn't give those details when you asked your question. Proper SO etiquette would be for you to close this question and ask a new one with your actual problem. As it is right now if someone finds this question and looks at the accepted solution it won't solve the question asked.

Comment: My, fault...I accept it, of course. I accept both of them! :)

Answer (score 0):

insert `reset($row2)` after second while. u need to reset loop to the first and loop again.
in `mysqli` `fetch_assoc()` use `data_seek(0)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a better solution, this is what I'm searching for!